# Downloading video file from Mysql DB in java

Tags: java, mysql, video

I am trying to download video file stored as blob in Mysql. The file gets downloaded fine but it gets corrupted i guess. The formats to downloaded are ogg, webm n mp3. The problem is that wen i try to convert any video using ffmpeg, it says "invalid data found during processing".

I am using the following code

```
    Blob image = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
     try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con = MySqlConnect.getDBConnection();
     String sql = "select videos, filename from sun.videostore where  id ='"+fileID+"'";
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
     while (rs.next()) {
    String filename = rs.getString("filename");
    Blob video = rs.getBlob("videos");
    File file1 = new File("C:\\DowloadFile\\" + filename); 
    FileOutputStream foStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    if( video != null){ 
        int length = (int) video.length();
        InputStream is2 = video.getBinaryStream();
        int b = 0;
        while(b!=-1){
         b=is2.read();
         foStream.write(b);
        }

    }

    }           
  }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Ecxeption in getting data from DB = "+e);
  }'
```

Comment: I'd check frist if the video is definately not corrupted in the database as well. Use a tool like MySQL Query Browser, download the blob to a file with it, then run ffmpeg against it.

Comment: Thanx for a quick reply....i wll check tat...Is there a requirement to set codecs after u write bytes to file in java. I tried this code on ogg n the video is playing firefox. However not on chrome, which is another problem i am facing

Comment: The codec is normally included in the file header. I have stored videos, pictures and music in a mysql database before and just dump the bytes straight to file and play. There should be no need to set codec information once you dump the file. Sounds like the file is corrupted before upload to database like @0xCAFEBABE mentions.

Comment: No i have checked my uploaded file, it is not corrupted....I have tried a different way to upload the video into DB. FileInputStream File video = new File(filename);                                   fis = new FileInputStream(video); 
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) video.length());//preparedStatement   If i upload the file in above way, i get a correct file on downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No i have checked my uploaded file, it is not corrupted....I have tried a different way to upload the video into DB.

```
File video = new File(filename);                                   
fis = new FileInputStream(video); 
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) video.length());//preparedStatement
```

If i upload the file in above way, i get a correct file on downloading.

Comment: If it solved your problem. Accept the answer by clicking correct sign.